# Why is not my HTML form sending the data to my JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am working on a simple ASP.NET project. I have HTML and a JS file. I am trying to send the values of the form inputs to the JS file, but it seems to be broken for some reason. 
My form looks like:

```
<div class="set-the-clock">
    <form name="settheclock">
        <span>Hours: </span><input type="text" id="fhours" value=""><br>
        <span>Minutes: </span><input type="text" id="fminutes" value=""><br>
        <span>Seconds: </span><input type="text" id="fseconds" value=""><br>
        <input type="button" id="send" value="Enter">
    </form>
```

and my JS is:

```
var setHour = document.getElementById("fhours").value;
var setMinute = document.getElementById("fminutes").value;
var setSecond = document.getElementById("fseconds").value;
```

and the function that meant to use it:

```
 function setTheClockByButton() {
    setTheClock(setHour, setMinute, setSecond);
    alert(setHour);
 }
```

If I put a number to the value in the HTML form it works fine(like this)

```
<span>Hours: </span><input type="text" id="fhours" value="3"><br>
```

but it not accepting any data from the keyboard.

And of course I have the onclick function associated to the form:

```
 document.getElementById("send").onclick = setTheClockByButton;
```

(otherwise it'd make no sense).

Comment: You don't have asocciated event to check if the value is changed.

Comment: The assignment statements where you get the field values only happens once. The code does not create some sort of permanent relationship between those variables and the field values. When the field values change because a user types something, the variables will not be updated.

Comment: I just edited the post, I had the onclick function, I have forgotten to mention it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move those assignment statements inside the function:

```
 function setTheClockByButton() {
    var setHour = document.getElementById("fhours").value;
    var setMinute = document.getElementById("fminutes").value;
    var setSecond = document.getElementById("fseconds").value;

    setTheClock(setHour, setMinute, setSecond);
    alert(setHour);
 }
```

Now each time the button is clicked (and note that I'm assuming that part works, since you say it does), the values of the input fields will be fetched so that the clock update function is working with up-to-date values.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `onclick` event:

```
<div class="set-the-clock">
    <form name="settheclock">
        <span>Hours: </span><input type="text" id="fhours" value=""><br>
        <span>Minutes: </span><input type="text" id="fminutes" value=""><br>
        <span>Seconds: </span><input type="text" id="fseconds" value=""><br>
        <input type="button" id="send" value="Enter" onclick="setTheClockByButton()">
    </form>
</div>

<script>

function setTheClockByButton() {
   var setHour = document.getElementById("fhours").value;
   var setMinute = document.getElementById("fminutes").value;
   var setSecond = document.getElementById("fseconds").value;
   alert(setHour);
}

</script>
```

Comment: The code I gave you above is working. Did you try it ?

Comment: I have already created the onclick event, the problem was with the scopes. Now it is alright, thanks for helping.